# Is the function $(x^2+y^2)\sin\frac{1}{x^4+y^4}$ differentiable at point $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The function is defined as

$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}(x^2+y^2)\sin\frac{1}{x^4+y^4}&(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{array}\right.$$

How do I find out if the function is differentiable at point $\;(0,0)\;?$

At first it's clear that the function is continuous, because limit at $(0,0)$ is the same as value of function at $(0,0)$.

It's also clear that the function is differentiable in all $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$. Now it's only left to figure out the differentiability at $(0,0)$.

My take on it was that we know how does a total differential of a function looks like
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$
so we need to check if the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ exist. From definition we have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x,0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin\frac{1}{x^4}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\left(x\sin\frac{1}{x^4}\right)=0$$
Same goes for partial derive with respect to $y$. Am I correct, if now I conclude that the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ or is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: For $v=(x,y)\neq 0$, you have $\vert f(v) \vert \le \Vert v \Vert \Vert v\Vert$ which enables to conclude immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something else that needs to be done in order to conclude that the function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

You have to verify that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f_x(0,0)\,x-f_y(0,0)\,y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$$

where $\;f_x(0,0)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)\;$ and $\;f_y(0,0)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)\;.$

**Proof :**

Since $\;f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0\;,\;$ we get that

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{f(x,y)-f_x(0,0)\,x-f_y(0,0)\,y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=$

$\quad=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=$

$\quad=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\left(x^2+y^2\right)\sin\left(\frac1{x^4+y^4}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=$

$\quad=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sin\left(\dfrac1{x^4+y^4}\right)=$

$\quad=0\;$

indeed the product of an infinitesimal function by a bounded function is an infinitesimal function.

**Geometric interpretation of differentiability :**
Geometrically, a function is differentiable at a point $P_0(x_0,y_0)$ if there exists the tangent plane to the graph of the function at the point $P_0$ and, in a neighbourhood of the point $P_0$, the graph of the function can be linearly approximated by the tangent plane.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I get to this expression though? What is the reason for subtracting the partial derivatives? And is there a reason for it to be equal to 0 or would it be 0 for all functions? Does it have to something with the total derivative formula?

Comment: Only differentiable functions have that limit equal to $0$. So, if you want to verify whether a function is differentiable or not, you need to calculate that limit. See this site that contains the answers to all your questions : https://users.math.msu.edu/users/abbasc/math234-s05/Mth234SupMat12-3.pdf